# Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 6

Tags: php, preg-match

im not sure why this wont work... works perfectly in multiple `regex` checkers and testers. but when it comes to running it in `PHP` i get this error:

```
Warning: `preg_match()` [function.preg-match]: 
Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 6 in /home/splose/public_html/index/index.php on line 49
```

im running this:

```
if(preg_match('[\\/^$.|?*+():<>]', $username)){}
```

Comment: I believe you have to start and end your regex with a forward slash `/` no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you can try to delimit your pattern?:

```
if(preg_match('/[\\/^$.|?*+():<>]/', $username)){}
```

Taken directly from the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) :

```
Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and tildes (~).
```

Comment: aah cheers, it worked! i thought i tried using delimiters. Anyways thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use regex expression with delimiters forward slashes (/)

```
// wrong pattern
$pattern = '[\\/^$.|?*+():<>]';
// right pattern
$pattern = '/[\\/^$.|?*+():<>]/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $username)){}
```